# Why can't the base of a logarithm be negative?

Tags: logarithms

I understand why the base of a logarithm can't be 0 or 1, but why negative?

What I found out is that when the base is negative we get imaginary results when the powers are rational numbers with odd denominators, for example:

$$-2^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

is undefined, thus the logarithm is not defined either?

Is this true? and if it's, is that the only reason?
Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the example you posted is defined, because it is the square root of 2 with a negative up front

Comment: Do you mean it's equivalent to $-1 * \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: I would put parentheses around the $(-2)$.

Comment: OP already asked essentially the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690024/why-must-the-base-of-a-logarithm-be-a-positive-real-number-not-equal-to-1)

Comment: Really didn't get that part :)

Comment: @MJD, Note that your link starts https: which causes Latex not to render correctly.