# Negative-base logarithm, where's the issue here

Tags: logarithms, real-numbers

Here we go again, basics of the basics. Faced with the following question.

**Definitions**

Logarithm base `a` of `x` is by definition a number such as:

$$a^{\log_a x} = x$$

i.e. that answers the question "what power do I have to raise `a` in order to get `x`". I've read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690052/360748) about why logarithms can't be negative-based but that leaves out the case of "well-behaved" negative numbers.

$$(-2)^{3} = -8$$

so it is natural to expect that using the definition above and setting `a = -2` and `x = -8` we can define a logarithm in this case:

$$\log_{-2} (-8) = 3$$

which breaks the rule that requires the base of the logarithm to be positive and not 1, but sort of makes sense.

**Question**

Following the rule of the base change, we can now do the following:

$$3 = \log_{-2} (-8) = {\log_2 (-8)\over \log_2 (-2)}$$

and now, that definitely makes no sense because on the left side we have something that's well-defined and on the right side we have something that's not defined at all, because there is no power that `2` can be raised to to yield `-2` or `-8`. So my question is - where is the mistake? Which definition went wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitions aren't right or wrong; claims about their consequences are. In this case, you've chosen $a,\,b,\,c$ so that $\log_ab=\frac{\log_ca}{\log_cb}$ breaks down; indeed, so will the proof of it.

The tricky thing about negative-base logarithms is that, unless you're prepared for them to be complex-valued, the set of values they can take isn't continuous. For example, what's $\log_{-2}3$? Well unfortunately, no real $x$ solves $(-2)^x=3$; in fact, $x,\,(-2)^{x}$ can only both be real if $x$ is a rational number which, in its lowest terms, has an odd denominator.

Comment: So, to reiterate: we don't want negative log bases if we aren't in a complex world because on a real number line such a log will no longer be a nice function? (nice = continuous and what not)

Comment: @AlmaDo Worse still, the set of values on which it's defined (with a real value) wouldn't include any intervals of positive width.

Comment: Great!! This last comment answers my question (and I'm all fine with the log being "not well behaved" on a negative number line half so long as it is consistent with it being properly defined on some points on it)