# Inequality: $(x-1)\log_{x+3}(x+2)\log_3(x+3)^2\le0$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

One step of solve this is :[image]

I dont understand, why  $x+3\neq1$ ?
We solve it with function domain help.
If $\log_3(1)^2$ this may exist but not true, and if $x+3\neq2$ may exist but not true. If $\log_{1}(x+2)$ then $(x+2)^0$ is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that if $a^b = c$, then $\log_a c = b$ and vice versa. So if $\log_{x+3} (x+2)$ was defined and equalled $u$, there would be some $u$ where $(x+3)^u = (x+2)$, which is absurd.

Alternatively, by the change of base formula, it would equal $\frac{\log(x+2)}{\log (x+3)}$, where $\log(x+3) \ne 0$ to avoid division by $0$, and raising both sides to the power of the given base, $x+3 \ne 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The base of a logarithm cannot be $1$. So, assuming $$\log_ax$$ is a function of both $a$ and $x$, the domain is $x > 0$ and $a > 0, a\ne 1$.

For more details, [check this out.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690024/why-must-the-base-of-a-logarithm-be-a-positive-real-number-not-equal-to-1)

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Logarithm definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) the defining relation between exponentiation and logarithm is:

${\displaystyle \log _{b}(x)=y\ }$ exactly if ${\displaystyle \ b^{y}=x\ } and {\displaystyle \ x>0}$ and ${\displaystyle \ b\neq 1}$

Thus base can't be $1$.

However if $x+3=1$ then [image]

the part in rectangle in above picture in that the base will become $1$ which contradicts the definition. Thus $a+3$ is not equal to $1$.