# Logarithms with negative integer bases.

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms, real-numbers

I know this question has been asked before, but I am still now convinced with the explanations from previous questions like this one:

[Why must the base of a logarithm be a positive real number not equal to 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690024/why-must-the-base-of-a-logarithm-be-a-positive-real-number-not-equal-to-1)

Say a function $f$ follows the rule $f: D \to \mathbb R, f(x) = \log_{-2}{x}, D \in \mathbb Z$

The *real* range is definitely $\mathbb Z^+$.

However, the *real* domain, $D$ can be defined as in two parts where all the odd powers of $-2$ result in $-x$: ${(-2, -8, -32...)}$ and the even powers will similarly be $+x$.

What I do want to know is why do logarithmic functions with negative bases not exist (undefined) when their inverse exist for negative values of $x$ exist and therefore why isn't $D$ defined for certain, negative and positive **set** of values, as the function theoretically exists?

Comment: What value of $x$ solves $(-2)^x=3$?

Comment: @EverywhereDense No, thats why I said "set of values"

Comment: Also, your assertion that (where $f$ is well defined), the Real range of $f$ is $\Bbb{Z^+}$ is wrong for two reasons:  [1] What value of $x$ satisfies the equation $(-2)^x = [-2]^{(1/3)}, $ which is a well defined number? [2] What value of $x$ satisfies the equation $(-2)^x = \frac{-1}{8}$?

Comment: @user2661923 I already specified  ∈ ℤ, although your second point is valid

Comment: Good catch.  My mistake for not reading your question closely enough.

Comment: I'm really not sure why this was downvoted so hard.

Comment: @infinitezero The score is just $-1$

Comment: @Peter the score,  yes, but only since it got some upvotes in the meantime. Click on the number and you should be able to see the amount of votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\text{Using change of base}, \\\log_{-2} x=\frac{\log x}{\log (-2)}$$

$$\text{But} \log (-2)=y\Rightarrow10^y=-2\text{  which is impossible for real values $y$.}$$

Comment: I know it does not work when using change of base laws, but does that mean we just ignore other ways to solve it (that work)??

Comment: No doubt, you may choose some appropriate domain and codomain of the $\log$ function and make it work. I doubt it won't be a "good-looking" domain/codomain.